# How to get cpu usage for every core with a bash script using standard *nix tools

Tags: bash, shell-script, x11, dwm

I'm writing a bash script to print system stats to my `dwm` status bar using `xsetroot`. Everything works as expected. What I'm currently missing is an easy way that just uses standard `*nix` tools to give me the current load for every core on my system (I have 4 cores.). I can't figure out how to do this e.g. using `top`. All other posts I found on this site so far just deal with average load. Has anybody done this before?

The main reason that I want it for every single core is to have a cheap and rough tool to check if a program is running some code I wrote in parallel (e.g. a for each loop).

Comment: watch `/proc/stat`, I don't offhand know what all of those numbers translate to, but `man procfs` probably does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Calculating the average per core usage from `/proc/stat`

The best solution I have come up so far uses `bc` to account for floating point arithmetic:

```
# Calculate average cpu usage per core.
#      user  nice system   idle iowait irq softirq steal guest guest_nice
# cpu0 30404 2382   6277 554768   6061   0      19    0      0          0
A=($(sed -n '2,5p' /proc/stat))
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
B0=$((${A[1]}  + ${A[2]}  + ${A[3]}  + ${A[4]}))
B1=$((${A[12]} + ${A[13]} + ${A[14]} + ${A[15]}))
B2=$((${A[23]} + ${A[24]} + ${A[25]} + ${A[26]}))
B3=$((${A[34]} + ${A[35]} + ${A[36]} + ${A[37]}))
sleep 2
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
C=($(sed -n '2,5p' /proc/stat))
D0=$((${C[1]}  + ${C[2]}  + ${C[3]}  + ${C[4]}))
D1=$((${C[12]} + ${C[13]} + ${C[14]} + ${C[15]}))
D2=$((${C[23]} + ${C[24]} + ${C[25]} + ${C[26]}))
D3=$((${C[34]} + ${C[35]} + ${C[36]} + ${C[37]}))
# cpu usage per core
E0=$(echo "scale=1; (100 * ($B0 - $D0 - ${A[4]}   + ${C[4]})  / ($B0 - $D0))" | bc)
E1=$(echo "scale=1; (100 * ($B1 - $D1 - ${A[15]}  + ${C[15]}) / ($B1 - $D1))" | bc)
E2=$(echo "scale=1; (100 * ($B2 - $D2 - ${A[26]}  + ${C[26]}) / ($B2 - $D2))" | bc)
E3=$(echo "scale=1; (100 * ($B3 - $D3 - ${A[37]}  + ${C[37]}) / ($B3 - $D3))" | bc)
echo $E0
echo $E1
echo $E2
echo $E3
```

The average cpu usage per core can be directly computed from `/proc/stat` (Credits to @mikeserv for the hint for using `/proc/stat`.):

```
# Here we make use of bash direct array assignment
A0=($(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat))
A1=($(sed '3q;d' /proc/stat))
A2=($(sed '4q;d' /proc/stat))
A3=($(sed '5q;d' /proc/stat))
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
B0=$((${A0[1]} + ${A0[2]} + ${A0[3]} + ${A0[4]}))
B1=$((${A1[1]} + ${A1[2]} + ${A1[3]} + ${A1[4]}))
B2=$((${A2[1]} + ${A2[2]} + ${A2[3]} + ${A2[4]}))
B3=$((${A3[1]} + ${A3[2]} + ${A3[3]} + ${A3[4]}))
sleep 0.2
C0=($(sed '2q;d' /proc/stat))
C1=($(sed '3q;d' /proc/stat))
C2=($(sed '4q;d' /proc/stat))
C3=($(sed '5q;d' /proc/stat))
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
D0=$((${C0[1]} + ${C0[2]} + ${C0[3]} + ${C0[4]}))
D1=$((${C1[1]} + ${C1[2]} + ${C1[3]} + ${C1[4]}))
D2=$((${C2[1]} + ${C2[2]} + ${C2[3]} + ${C2[4]}))
D3=$((${C3[1]} + ${C3[2]} + ${C3[3]} + ${C3[4]}))
# cpu usage per core
E0=$(((100 * (B0 - D0 - ${A0[4]} + ${C0[4]})) / (B0 - D0)))
E1=$(((100 * (B1 - D1 - ${A1[4]} + ${C1[4]})) / (B1 - D1)))
E2=$(((100 * (B2 - D2 - ${A2[4]} + ${C2[4]})) / (B2 - D2)))
E3=$(((100 * (B3 - D3 - ${A3[4]} + ${C3[4]})) / (B3 - D3)))
echo $E0
echo $E1
echo $E2
echo $E3
```

or even shorter by making extensive use of bash direct array assignment:

```
# Here we make use of bash direct array assignment by assigning line
# 2 to 4 to one array


A=($(sed -n '2,5p' /proc/stat))
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
B0=$((${A[1]}  + ${A[2]}  + ${A[3]}  + ${A[4]}))
B1=$((${A[12]} + ${A[13]} + ${A[14]} + ${A[15]}))
B2=$((${A[23]} + ${A[24]} + ${A[25]} + ${A[26]}))
B3=$((${A[34]} + ${A[35]} + ${A[36]} + ${A[37]}))
sleep 0.2
# user         + nice     + system   + idle
C=($(sed -n '2,5p' /proc/stat))
D0=$((${C[1]}  + ${C[2]}  + ${C[3]}  + ${C[4]}))
D1=$((${C[12]} + ${C[13]} + ${C[14]} + ${C[15]}))
D2=$((${C[23]} + ${C[24]} + ${C[25]} + ${C[26]}))
D3=$((${C[34]} + ${C[35]} + ${C[36]} + ${C[37]}))
# cpu usage per core
E0=$((100 * (B0 - D0 - ${A[4]}  + ${C[4]})  / (B0 - D0)))
E1=$((100 * (B1 - D1 - ${A[15]} + ${C[15]}) / (B1 - D1)))
E2=$((100 * (B2 - D2 - ${A[26]} + ${C[26]}) / (B2 - D2)))
E3=$((100 * (B3 - D3 - ${A[37]} + ${C[37]}) / (B3 - D3)))
echo $E0
echo $E1
echo $E2
echo $E3
```

### A `top` based solution

This can also be achieved without installing an additional tool with `top` only (I used this in a later [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153029/how-to-print-a-bash-variable-that-has-an-array-as-value).) By default `top` does only show the average cpu load when it is started but it will show all cpus when you press `1`. To be able to use `top`'s cpu output when we use it in batch output mode we will need to make this the default behaviour when `top` is started. This can be done by using a `~/.toprc` file. Fortunately this can be automatically created: Start `top` press `1` and press `W` which will generate the `~/.toprc` file in your homefolder. When you now run `top -bn 1 | grep -F '%Cpu'` you will see that `top` now outputs all of your cores. Now we have already everything we will need to make this work. All the information I need is in column `3` of the array that will be the output of `top`.

There is only one problem: When the cpu usage for a core reaches `100%` the array that the command outputs will move the column with the current load from column `3` to column `2`. Hence, with `awk '{print $3}'` you will then see `us,` as output for column `3`. If you're fine with that leave it. If not your could have `awk` print column `2` as well. It will just be `:`. A solution that avoids all those pitfalls is:

```
top -bn 2 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | gawk '{print $2 $3}' | tr -s '\n\:\,[:alpha:]' ' '
```

it strips the output of all newlines `\n`, `,` and letters `[:alpha:]` and removes all but one single whitespace `-s`.

Answer (score 8):

This creates a bash array whose elements are the loads for each CPU:

```
loads=($(mpstat -P ALL 1 1 | awk '/Average:/ && $2 ~ /[0-9]/ {print $3}'))
```

Since bash arrays are numbered starting with zero, the load of the second CPU would be printed with:

```
echo ${loads[1]}
```

This requires the utility `mpstat`.  To install it on a debian-like system, run:

```
apt-get install sysstat
```

#### How it works

The somewhat verbose output produced by `mpstat` looks like:

```
$ mpstat -P ALL 1 1
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 (MyMachine)     08/30/2014      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

10:12:35 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:12:36 PM  all    1.49    0.00    1.49    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.01
10:12:36 PM    0    0.00    0.00    2.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.98
10:12:36 PM    1    1.96    0.00    1.96    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.08

Average:     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
Average:     all    1.49    0.00    1.49    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.01
Average:       0    0.00    0.00    2.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.98
Average:       1    1.96    0.00    1.96    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.08
```

where `-P ALL` tells `mpstat` to show all cpus and the arguments `1 1` tell it to print output every second and stop after the first second.

To select just the values that we want, this `awk` command is used:

```
awk '/Average:/ && $2 ~ /[0-9]/ {print $3}'
```

This selects only the final lines (the ones starting with `Average:` and, among those, only select those whose second column is numeric.  For those lines, the third column (cpu load) is printed.

Because of the use of parentheses, the output from the `mpstat`-`awk` pipeline is captured into a bash array.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution and it works for me.

```
echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python
```

Source (write up):
https://mohammadg.com/programming/how-to-get-overall-cpu-utilization-from-the-bash-command-line/

Answer (score -1):

you can see the frequency for each core with the following:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: The OP asked for CPU load per core expressed as a percentage, not the clock frequency.