# How to print a bash variable that has an array as value

Tags: bash, shell-script, xorg, x11, dwm

I wrote a script for my `dwm` statusbar. One part of it is finding the current cpu usage for every single core on my system. I figured out a way myself but I would need some help fixing a bug in this. Here is the command: `top -bn 2 -d 0.5 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | awk '{print $3}'`. This assumes that your `top` shows every core per default. You can achieve this by issuing `top` then pressing `1` and then pressing `W` to save the current configuration to a `.toprc` file in your home folder. Everytime you open `top` now it will display all of your cores. My aforementioned command has the drawback that when assigned to a variable like this:

```
CPU=$(top -bn 2 -d 0.5 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | awk '{print $3}')
```

and then using `$CPU` with `xsetroot` like this: `xsetroot -name "$CPU"` I will get the output I want in my statusbar but between every cpu percentage there will be two symbols on top of each other separating them `v` and `t`. How do I get rid of them? Has this something to do that I might be using an array instead of a string here?

You can see the problem on the left side of the [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wplfy640d5t3n4/screen.jpg?dl=0).

Command:

```
top -bn 2 -d 0.5 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | awk '{print $3}'
```

sample output:

```
14.3
12.0
8.0
10.0
```

---

Note for anyone using this script: When the cpu usage for a core reaches `100%` the array that the command outputs will move the column with the current load from column `3` to column `2`. Hence, with `awk '{print $3}'` you will then see `us,` as output for column `3`. If you're fine with that leave it. If not you could have `awk` print column `2` as well. It will just be `:`. A solution that avoids all those pitfalls is:

```
top -bn 2 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | gawk '{print $2 $3}' | tr -s '\n\:\,[:alpha:]' ' '
```

Comment: Fell free to edit the title if you have a better one.

Comment: Which OS do you use and post output of `top -bn 2 -d 0.5`.

Comment: `Archlinux` with kernel version `3.16.1-1-ARCH`; `x86-64`. You really don't wanna see the ouput of `top -bn 2 -d 0.5` that will be an aweful long list of running processes...

Comment: Off-topic: you may prefer to read `/proc/stat` to get the same information more cheaply. See `proc(5)`.

Comment: Thought about this too... Do you have a solution at hand how to do this?

Comment: it might be useful (and probably faster) to calculate it: 
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat

Comment: I'm currently working on something like that. Will post soon.

Comment: @aecolley and @wmmso I tried using `/proc/stat`. You can judge how succesful this has been for yourself here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/how-to-get-cpu-usage-for-every-core-with-a-bash-script/153039#153039. Corrections more than welcome if I should have made a mistake regarding the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "stuff" between the values seems a visual representation of the newline character to me ( octal character code 12), which you would get when using:

```
echo -e 'a\012b'
```

What you could try is pipe the output through `tr '\n' ' '` as with:

```
echo -e 'a\012b' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Cheers, you were close! It seems it's not a visual representation of the vertical tab bar but rather a newline. As I suspected the problem might be that I assign a `4x1` array to a bash variable and pass this to `xsetroot`. By removing the newline I get either a string or a `1x4` array. I'm not sure. So I need to pipe the output through `tr '\n' ' '`. Could you update your answer?

Comment: I believe the rogue character is a newline (i.e. linefeed), even though it is displayed as VT. Therefore the correct filter is `tr '\012' ' '`.